# Creating reusable Linq queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a select query which is used over and over with different `where` filters:

```
var query = from row in context.Table select row;
```

How can I save this into a static class variable so I can reuse it in different methods? Like:

```
var results1 = query.Where(condition1);
...
var results2 = query.Where(condition2);
```

Comment: I don't get it. How is what you want different from what you already have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Consider creating a new method instead of a variable:

```
public IQueryable<Cust> ListActiveCustomers()
{
     return dataContext.Customers.Where(c=>c.IsActive==true);
}
```

You can then consume this from anywhere that method is visible:

```
 //Active Customers with no invoices due.
 var activePaidCustomers = ListActiveCustomers().Where(c=>c.InvoicesDue==0)
                                                .OrderByDescending(c=>c.LastPaidOn)
                                                .ToList();
```

Comment: Since I don't have a global ObjectContext I've created a parameterized List() method: private IQueryable<Cust> List(MyContext ctx){ return ctx.Customers...}..

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
Expression<Func<TypeYoureQueryingAgainst, bool>> query = p => p.Value == someValue; // etc..
```

Then you could do the following, where TypeYoureQueryingAgainst is in the repository or whatever pattern you're using:

```
repository.Where(query);
```

Hope that makes sense..

Comment: Makes sense...somewhat. How do I send parameter to it? I've created this: Expression<Func<MyTable, int, bool>> query = (table, id) => table.Id == id;. I can use it as context.MyTable.Where(query) but how can I send id parameter to "query"?

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
var query = from row in context.Table select row;
```

Is functionally equivalent to:

```
var query = context.Table;
```

So you don't need to keep this `query` variable to reuse it, just use `context.Table` directly:

```
var results1 = context.Table.Where(condition1);
...
var results2 = context.Table.Where(condition2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `var` with `IEnumerable<RowType>` (or `IQueryable<RowType>`) where `RowType` is the (non-anonymous) type of each item in the result sequence:

```
static IEnumerable<RowType> query = from ... select row; // row is of RowType.
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first step is finding out the exact type of `query`.  The easiest way is to step through so code using it in the debugger, and see what it says the type is (probably `IQueryable<RowType>` or `IOrderedQueryable<RowType>`)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative if your `where` filters are simple scalars is to create extension method(s) on the `DbSet` properties of your database context.

If your `DbContext` is like:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get;set; }
    ...
}
```

You can create reusable queries on the `Customers` `DbSet` like:

```
public static class MyDbContextExtension
{
   public static IEnumerable<Customer> GetByName(this DbSet<Customer> customers, string name)
   {
       return customers.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(name));
   }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
var context = new MyContext();
var jedis = context.Customers.GetByName("skywalker");
if(jedis.Any())
{
    logger.Log("These aren't the customers you're looking for");
}
```